# Asp.net 5 Stopped working after using IHttpConnectionFeature

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to get remote IP address in Asp.net Vnext.

after i added this line in my code , the page stopped working in published IIS

server (no error appears , only white screen) :

```
var remoteIpAddress = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress;
```

also when i checked the result in local IIS-Express it gives me this :

[image]

this my project.json file :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "DataAccessComponents": "1.0.0-*",
    "Utility": "1.0.0-*",
    "AdModels": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.22",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Net.Primitives": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "System.Text.Encoding": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Net.Http.WebRequest": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Also im using normal IIS 8 for my project and im not gonna port this program to another OS.

should i change the "Web" Section in project json ? Like adding iis or something ?

Comment: Please show the code from your `Get` method that is getting the error.

Comment: @DavidTansey thanks for respond. there isnt much code in Get method.
its sample project with default MVC application template , just like in picture.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm still having this issue on RC1-final.

Comment: @PaulKnopf sadly the issue still exist ...